# Multi-activity really needed on Android?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

I'm used to HTML development. Now I'm starting to program my first Android apps. In the tutorials I have read it looks like Android development favors using a new activity for each different form.

Nothing-less I think it's quite possible to use a single activity and use the setVisibility(View.VISIBLE|View.INVISIBLE) to show / hide GUI forms elements (This is much more similar to what I'm used with HTML-AJAX).

Is there something wrong with this way of development in Android?

Using a single activity(process) also allow to use singletons to share state and data between GUI components, while the multi-activity requires a "slightly" complex communication system using extra data to communicate the selected id, ...

I wonder what are the disadvantages of the single Activity "pattern" and why no tutorial/manual on the Internet use this technique to develop Android apps.

Do fragments have any advantage over showing/hiding views when I have no  intention/interest to reuse the component?

Comment: Instead of preloading _all_ UI's (which may be _very_ time/resource consuming), you can easily swap them out in the same `Activity`. E.g. `container.removeView(current); container.add(newView);`. See the 'Custom Views' section of [this article](https://corner.squareup.com/2014/10/advocating-against-android-fragments.html).

Comment: What you are describing, in HTML terms, is a single-page application approach. Relatively few Web apps are single-page apps. You can build them, and there are some advantages for doing so, and there are some frameworks that make it easier to do so. However, nobody is forcing Web developers at gunpoint to make single-page Web apps, AFAIK, and there are costs for making such apps. If you step back and think of what the concerns are with single-page Web apps, you will probably find that there are analogues to those concerns with respect to single-activity Android apps.

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27725473/why-not-always-use-fragments-with-one-activity/27726891#27726891

Comment: @hnaarman, thanks for sharing the "WTFs/min = 2^fragment count" formula really convinced me that fragments are not a good idea in the long term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Approach : Single Activity :

- This approach will show/hide UI elements based on user interaction with app. Showing a UI Element draws View hierarchy starting from that element. This is called **Layout Pass**. This layout passes are expensive operation when performance is calculated. This is not advisable way to implement.

Approach : Single Activity, Multiple Fragment :

- This approach will also have Single Activity but multiple Fragments associated with this activity. Each fragment defines new UI screen based on application requirement. More details available : [Android Developer Guide : Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) This is much advisable way to implement your requirement

Answer (score 1):

I think there is nothing wrong, but depending on how complex your app will be, the source code can easily become very confusing!

Answer (score 0):

Do you want those code happen:

```
elementXScreenA.setVisibility(false);
elementYScreenA.setVisibility(false);
elementZScreenA.setVisibility(false);

elementXScreenB.setVisibility(true);
elementYScreenB.setVisibility(true);
elementZScreenB.setVisibility(true);
```

And then, maybe after that:

```
elementXScreenB.setVisibility(false);
elementYScreenB.setVisibility(false);
elementZScreenB.setVisibility(false);

elementXScreenC.setVisibility(true);
elementYScreenC.setVisibility(true);
elementZScreenC.setVisibility(true);
```

**No. I don't want to do that !!!**

That just base on your ways for funny. There are many many disadvantages to do that, and I don't think there are any advantages in this approach. I can list some. Any comments will add to this list:

1. **Design UI**. How can you code multi layout on one xml layout file? Android Studio doesn't support this. You will see elements overlap elements
2. **Performance**. Load all your application UI is not an intelligent way. You lost memory, lost CPU. Although you set invisible, your memory still store those information, and when transition between elements, invisible elements still count into.
3. **Maintainable**.  I'm working with a medium project, and still headache every day with bigger and bigger fragment and activity. (in case that each layout for each activity/fragment). How does everything become when you make all your layouts into one activity?
4. **Collaboration**. All layouts in one file. All your application in one file. How can you can collaborate between members? Code conflict, wrong edit ... Noooo. Stop that :)

No. Stop that. You just make element invisible when that element need this. For example, floating button when user scroll down list, error message textbox when no error need to show, ...

Comment: Downvoter ? Any comments, please? If you don't satisfy with my answer, please tell me. Or I can delete this "useless" answer :)

Comment: Some doubts about your notes:


 - Multi-layout could be done programatically by inflating new views. Is that correct?


 - Respect to performance, maybe container.add/remove is a (much) better approach to save memory (I wasn't aware of this possibility).


 - With regards to collaboration, I think it would be better to isolate different dev work "into"  different Activities, but It was not my concern at this momment. I guess you are completely right in that case. (I'm just starting with Android dev, trying to make a simple app with some forms, and I'm working alone).

Comment: You can still have multiple people working on the project. Just define one ui set per xml file, then include them into one "parent" xml file

Comment: @AleksG By this way or that way, you can solve some issues, but just in small scale. When bigger, will there some confuses between members. There are many things I don't include in my post. For example, if you use different xml for each screen (but just one activity, and of course one fragment), how do you handle back stack ? And of course, you will have some ways. but that is not the TRUE way, and there will have some other problems appear, again and again ....

Comment: Agree. I didn't say it was a good idea, just that there are are ways of dealing with it.